# EditText Validation on login screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been having this issue for a few hours. I have a simple login page but I want to make a user input something instead of just clicking the login button.

I have pasted my code underneath

`username_register` is the `editText`

`login_button` is the `button` used to login

Thanks!

```
class FinanceLogin : AppCompatActivity () {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen)

        login_button.setOnClickListener{}
    }
    private fun validate() :Boolean {
        if (username_register.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            username_register.error = "Name cannot be blank"
            return false
        } else if (password_register.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            password_register.error = "Please enter your password"
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    override fun onClick(v: View?){
    when(v?.id){
        R.id.login_button->{
            if (validate()){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

    }}
}
```

Comment: What is your issue? And maybe you should username_register.text.isNullorEmpty() instead toString().isEmpty(). If your string is null then this will throw NullPointerException

Comment: are you using the normal edittext or textinputlayout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your issue is because if  condition in your case will only execute one of the two and that's why it is causing an issue , what you need to do is to validate each on its own , you can try the following code :

```
 // Function to validate Username

 private Boolean validateUsername(){
    if(username_register.text.toString().isEmpty()){
         username_register.error = "Name cannot be blank"
         return false 
     } else { 
         return true 
    }

  }
```

```
   // Function to validate Username

   private Boolean validatePassword(){
      if(password_register.text.toString().isEmpty()){
           password_register.error = "Please enter your password"
           return false 
       } else { 
           return true 
      }

    }
```

- Then in your button click listener

  ```
  override fun onClick(v: View?){
   when(v?.id){
       R.id.login_button->{
          if(validateUsername() &&  validatePassword()){
              // if both return true get the values from edittext and procced
          }
       }

   }}
  ```

Comment: I am not sure this is a problem because when he runs validate() it will first check if the username is blank, if it's not it will then go in else if() and check for a password. If both are not blank it will return true, but if one of them is blank it will return false and it won't log in. So I guess the code is working fine.